# Ubuntu: limiting user account only to access his home dir

Tags: linux, ubuntu, privileges, user

I just created new user account, but the new user is able to access all the directories structure (including other's home directories). I'd like to limit the user to access ONLY his home directory (and nothing "above"). How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Set the modes on all home directories to **0700**.

Optionally, set the default umask to `077`. In Ubuntu, edit the "`umask 022`" line in `/etc/profile`. Optionally, update PAM configuration in `/etc/pam.d/common-session` (`pam_umask.so umask=077 usergroups`).

Optionally, chmod `/etc/skel` and update `/etc/adduser.conf` (line "`DIR_MODE=0755`") to 0700.

---

You cannot restrict a user to "home directory and nothing \"above\"" without *a lot* of headache, and it does not make sense either (for me, at least):

- To execute any program, the user must have 'read' access to it.
- To use shared libraries, a program must have 'read' access to them.
- To read the system-wide configuration files and resources, 'read' access is needed too.

It is *write* access you should be afraid of, and the default permissions already prevent writing anywhere except a few locations.

Comment: ok, what are these "few locations"?! It's quite important for me.

Comment: @vic: `find / -xdev -type d -a \( -path "$HOME" -prune \) -o \( -writable -a -executable \) -ls 2>/dev/null` # this will list _directories_ that _you_ have write access to.

Comment: The few locations are files where passwords are stored in clear text, or other sensible data. For example, if you are using vpn and the pptp-linux packet. The password will be stored in /etc/ppp/pap-secrets or /etc/ppp/chap-secrets or in an folder above. Wich places this are depends really on your setup and your software. But in general the default rights for all files are set appropriate.

Comment: as i said: "But in general the default rights for all files are set appropriate.".

Answer (score 1):

This thread is little bit old but anyways you can restrict the users (very restrictive) to home directory by changing the bash shell to rbash if you really want it. By this way the user can't be able to use cd command. Or change the home directory owner as mentioned above. But remember that the user can execute bash so perform restrictive settings...